# Getting no image with error message while using camera to take photo in android

Tags: android, image, camera, android-permissions, permission-denied

I have implemented Camera and Gallery option to Take picture and choose from gallery accordingly in my app. After running the app, when I click camera option at first it takes permission from me.Now while taking a photo, the imageview become blank by giving error message that E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException. But when I go to gallery option, and  choose photo and it shows into imageview. Now if I go to camera option now, I can take photo and see in imageview. The problem is, if i click camera option at first, it does not work, but if i click it after gallery option it works.

My Code for taking pictire and picking up gallery image is

```
public class ViewProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_profile, container, false);

            image=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            saveData();
            return rootView;
        }
        public void saveData(){

                SharedPreferences preferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                String mImageUri = preferences.getString("image", null);
                if (mImageUri != null) {
                    image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mImageUri));
                    System.out.println("imageuri"+Uri.parse(mImageUri));
                } else {
                    Glide.with( this )
                            .load(Constants.HTTP.PHOTO_URL+mail)
                            .thumbnail(0.5f)
                            .override(200,200)
                            .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .into( image);

                         }


              }
        .....

    public void showDialog(){
        //Create a new builder and get the layout.
       ....
        alertListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // ListViekw Clicked item index
                if (position == 0) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                    alert.dismiss();
                    if(isPermissionGrantedCamera()&&isPermissionGrantedCameraWrite()) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    }
                }
                else if (position == 1){
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                    alert.dismiss();
                    if(isPermissionGrantedGallery()) {
                        galleryIntent();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            if(requestCode==CODE_GALLERY_REQUEST){
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    galleryIntent();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"You don't have permission to access gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            if(requestCode==MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE){
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    cameraIntent();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"You don't have permission to access gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult( requestCode, permissions, grantResults );
        }

        ......
        public  boolean isPermissionGrantedGallery() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                    return true;
                } else {

                    Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            }
        }


      public  boolean isPermissionGrantedCamera() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
     }

     public  boolean isPermissionGrantedCameraWrite() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission( Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

        private void galleryIntent()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);

        }

        public void cameraIntent() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File cameraFolder;
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    cameraFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image/");
                } else {
                    cameraFolder = getActivity().getCacheDir();
                }
                if (!cameraFolder.exists()) {
                    cameraFolder.mkdirs();
                }
                String imageFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                File photoFile = new File(cameraFolder + imageFileName);
                currentPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && data!=null){
                    onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
                }
                else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA ) {
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentPhotoPath)) {
                    try {
                        galleryAddPic();
                        onCaptureImageResult();
                        }
                      catch (Exception e){
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void galleryAddPic() {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
            this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            SharedPreferences preferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(uri));
            editor.commit();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void onCaptureImageResult() {
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromPath(currentPhotoPath, 200, 200);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            compressBitMap(bitmap);
        }

        private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
            uri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                currentPhotoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(currentPhotoPath));
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                currentPhotoPath = uri.getPath();
            }

            SharedPreferences preferences =
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(uri));
            editor.commit();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
            compressBitMap(bm);

        }

        private void compressBitMap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            ImageConversion imageConversion = new ImageConversion();
            byte[] bytesArray;
            int maxSize = 10 * 1024;
            int imageMaxQuality = 50;
            int imageMinQuality = 5;

            bytesArray = imageConversion.convertBitmapToByteArray(bitmap, imageMaxQuality, imageMinQuality, maxSize);
            File destination = new File(getContext().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytesArray);
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentPhotoPath = destination.getPath();
            uploadImage(bytesArray);
        }

        public static Bitmap getBitmapFromPath(String photoPath, int targetW, int targetH) {
            .....
        }

        //This code i sfor photo uploading
        private void uploadImage(final byte[] bytesArray){
            trustAllCertificates();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL+mail,

                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            Log.d( "Error Response"," "+response );
                            if(response.contains( "!DOCTYPE" )){
                                .....
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Photo is uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                            //Showing toast
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Server is not connected. Please check your internet connection" /*volleyError.getMessage().toString()*/, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d( "Volley Error"," "+volleyError );
                        }
                    }){

                @Override public byte[] getBody() {

                    return bytesArray;
                }


                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put( "Content-Type", "image/jpeg" );
                    headers.put( "Accept","*/*");
                    Log.d( "headers", String.valueOf( headers ) );
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Application.get().getRequestQueue();
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }

      }
```

And Manifest is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.com.and">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        .....

</manifest>
```

The Error Message

```
    09-25 08:59:30.351 5093-5093/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/image1506329962799.jpg (Permission denied)
09-25 08:59:30.352 5093-5093/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/image1506329962799.jpg (Permission denied)
```

Comment: try add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to permission checker

Comment: @Peter Sorry I could not understand, I think I alredy added write externnal storage

Comment: (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                 i dont see in your code WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: your error is :  (Permission denied) . So try to add this permission to runtime checker.

Comment: @Peter Do I need to create a new method for this, or I will include within, this, could you please explain based on my code. Sorry I am very new in developing android

Comment: make something like "isPermissionGrantedCamera" but for write_external_storage.

Comment: @Peter Can  I include it in  public  boolean isPermissionGrantedCamera() method in my code?

Comment: @Peter I have edited the code, I can take photo and see it in imgaeview, But the problem is it is taking permission for two times, that is annying for user How can I combine this two permission into one

Comment: this is google logic. U cant get all permission in one time. 2-3 ... 10 + If this permission dungerous - u need make a request runtime .